# IE8 Support Bootstrap3 + LESS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

He there,

I am currently working on a website with Bootstrap 3 + LESS css (http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-less-workflow-tutorial workflow), unfortunately I can't seem to get the IE8 support working. I have included the following line and scripts and they are linked correctly:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="defaults/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="defaults/js/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I compile the less files to one big minified .css file: styles.css. So I do not use @import or anything. For those of you interested, the CSS file can be found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64475407/styles.css and the index.html file can be found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64475407/index.html

Really hope someone can help me out :)

York

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers here you can find some info to get stuff working in browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens to be that the internet explorer 8 emulation modus of the IE11 browser isn't working the same as an actual IE8 browser.. When I tried it in a real IE8 browser, it was actually working haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap 3 isn't friendly for IE8 and below. I've had to use a polyfill to work with the border box-sizing which isn't supported in IE8

Give this a try: https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill

Comment: For this design I really need the media queries to work. The bootstrap3 documentation says it should be possible with the html5shiv.js and respond.js. Any idea why these do not work?

Comment: @YorkKeijzer I usually call the scripts after the CSS file if that helps?